# Android Sync Email on an Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I was able to get to work with email on an emulator few months ago, but due to some reasons i have formatted my system and now I’ve been trying for the last couple of days to sync my google account on Emulator. I get either of the following error messages:

1) If I use “myaddr@googlemail.com”, I get the error message: “Username or password incorrect”

2) If I use “myaddr@gmail.com”, I get the error message: “You don’t have permission to sync with this server. Contact your server’s administrator for more information.”

Any ideas what could be going wrong here? Is there a different way to approach this? I really need to send emails from my app for testing purpose....each and every time i don't want to use real device.